# MySql INSERT INTO variables ignore WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table 'users' and in this table i have 1 row with the username 'test'.
As soon as i try to fill these variables, he ignores the where condition and takes the first entry. what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT `username`, `password`, `active`, `login_attempts`, `mail`
INTO @username, @password, @active, @login_attempts, @mail
FROM `security`.`users`
WHERE `username` = 'ts';
SELECT @username;
```

result: @username: test

in this case it shouldn't return any value, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MySQL doesn't find any rows, it will *not* overwrite the variables with `null`, but it will keep the old values! So your final `select` will show you the username it contained before you did the `select ... into`, so probably the result from a previous run (in the same session) where you queried for an existing username.

Similarly, if you run your query without `into`, and you do not find a row, you will get 0 rows, not a row with `null` (that could be assigned to your variables).

To verify, run `select @username;` before your `select ... into`, it will contain the old username.

You need to (re)initialize the values before you run your query, e.g. do

```
SELECT null, null, null, null, null
INTO @username, @password, @active, @login_attempts, @mail;

SELECT username, password, active, login_attempts, mail
INTO @username, @password, @active, @login_attempts, @mail
FROM security.users
WHERE username = 'ts';

SELECT @username;
```

If you start a new session, the variable doesn't exist yet, which is why [sonus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62234451) worked for you, as it is the first query you run in a new session. You can get a similar effect if you hit the reconnect button in the MySQL workbench.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT username, password, active, login_attempts, mail
INTO @username, @password, @active, @login_attempts, @mail
FROM security.users
WHERE username = 'ts';
SELECT @username;`

try running this in the mysql for terminal usually stored in /usr/bin/mysql
run /usr/bin/mysql -u usernameOfYourComputer -p
if it works which it most probably will then its just a bug in mysql-workbench

Comment: yes it worked! do you have a recommendation which mysql gui i could use?

Comment: i usually do it on the terminal but when im not i use mysql-workbench myself.